Test coverage is lower when using Lombok @Builder
I have an issue with the test coverage with the Lombok's @Builder annotation.
I have a Java class annotated with Lombok's @Data, @AllArgsConstructor and @NoArgsConstructor:
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}

and a JUnit test-case:
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class UserTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
        assertNotNull(new User());
    }

}

My lombok.config is configured so that test coverage is ignored on generated code:
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation=true

IntelliJ shows a class test coverage of "100% (0/0)". That's expected as all code generated by Lombok is ignored from coverage.

When I add a @Builder annotation on class User, the coverage report shows "0% (0/1)":
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}


Testing the builder with assertNotNull(User.builder().build()) does not change the test coverage.
The IDE indicates that the line with the @Builder is not covered by tests:

The lombok.Generated annotation has been properly generated:
import lombok.Generated;

public class UserDelombok {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Generated
    public static UserBuilder builder() {
        return new UserBuilder();
    }

    @Generated
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Generated
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Generated
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Generated
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Generated
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        } else if (!(o instanceof User)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            User other = (User)o;
            if (!other.canEqual(this)) {
                return false;
            } else if (this.getId() != other.getId()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Object this$name = this.getName();
                Object other$name = other.getName();
                if (this$name == null) {
                    if (other$name != null) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else if (!this$name.equals(other$name)) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    @Generated
    protected boolean canEqual(Object other) {
        return other instanceof User;
    }

    @Generated
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 1;
        result = result * 59 + this.getId();
        Object $name = this.getName();
        result = result * 59 + ($name == null ? 43 : $name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Generated
    public String toString() {
        int var10000 = this.getId();
        return "User(id=" + var10000 + ", name=" + this.getName() + ")";
    }

    @Generated
    public UserDelombok(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Generated
    public UserDelombok() {
    }

    @Generated
    public static class UserBuilder {
        @Generated
        private int id;
        @Generated
        private String name;

        @Generated
        UserBuilder() { // not covered
        }

        @Generated
        public UserBuilder id(int id) { // not covered
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        @Generated
        public UserBuilder name(String name) { // not covered
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        @Generated
        public User build() { // not covered
            return new User(this.id, this.name);
        }

        @Generated
        public String toString() { // not covered
            return "User.UserBuilder(id=" + this.id + ", name=" + this.name + ")";
        }
    }
}

I'm using the following config:

Lombok 1.18.34
Junit Jupiter 5.10.3
IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2024.2.2

Why does does the coverage change when adding a new lombok annotation ?
How to get "100% (0/0)" coverage with @Builder ?
The full project to reproduce the issue:
https://github.com/jkronegg/lombok-builder-coverage

How do you collect coverage data?

I wonder what is considered not covered. If you call User.builder() in your test, does the coverage become 100%?

I cannot reproduce this issue with IntelliJ's code coverage feature, so I assume this is something wrong with Jacoco, or there are some other piece of crucial information that you didn't include.

The coverage comes from IntelliJ (in fact, I can also reproduce it with Jacoco, but staying in the IDE without Jacoco makes the test-case simpler). I added screenshots and link to a pet project in Github to demonstrate the issue.

I saw that an issue has been opened on IntelliJ https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-273961/IntelliJ-does-not-honor-lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotationtrue-and-reports-missing-coverage
